# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Onde foi que eu errei?   
    
    teste de formulario

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#meuForm').validate({
            rules:{
                nome:{
                required: true
                },
                email:{
                    required: true
                },
                telefonefixo:{
                    required: true
                },
                celular:{
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages:{
            nome:{
                required: "O campo é obrigatorio."
                },
                email:{
                    required: "O campo é obrigatorio."
                },
                telefonefixo:{
                    required: "O campo é obrigatorio."
                },
                celular:{
                    required: "O campo é obrigatorio."
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="meuForm" action="" method="POST">
NOME:<br>
<input type="text" name="nome" /><br>
Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email" /><br>
telefone fixo:<br>
<input type="text" name="telefonefixo" /><br>
Celular:<br>
<input type="text" name="celular" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="Cadastrar" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

sim ultilizei no header

```
 <script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" > </script>
```

Comment: Você incluiu a biblioteca jQuery no head da página?

Comment: sim ultilizei <script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" > </script>

Comment: A resposta do @LuisHenrique está correta. E também certifique-se de colocar as referências antes do script da pergunta

Comment: Não esqueça de definir um id ao seu form, para usar o validate, pois o #meuForm se referenciaria a um id e não ao name dele;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sua sintaxe de inclusão dos scripts está errada.

Não existe o atributo `href` para a tag script, mas sim `src`.

Substitua as inclusões por:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Qualquer dúvida, consulte o manual da w3s: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp