# Problemas com: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Há uma dúvida nesse forum [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52987/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined), mas não resolve meu problema. Tenho os includes, inclusive coloquei o include jquery na primeira linha porque nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456210/uncaught-reference-error-is-not-defined-error) achei isso:

> Because, JS interpreter search for $ before is even loaded and
>   defined.

O meu erro é o título desse post. Veja como está. No mesmo arquivo eu tenho o include, a função e o botão de chamada

```
<head>
<title><%=Application("app")%></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../gen/modal/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="\gen\css\css002.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Include the code and stylesheet for the grid control. -->
<script language="jscript.encode" src="../../gen/inc/ebagrid.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../gen/inc/styles/xp/eba.css" />

<script src="../../gen/js/cpaint2.inc.compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

Aqui o botão de chamada à função. Está comentada porque estou criando ela agora e vendo se está carregando do banco e etc:

```
<div><input type="button" id="btn" value="teste" onclick="CarregaTabela();" /></div>
```

E aqui a função javascript com jquery. A função se chama CarregaTabela:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var carregaDados = null;

    function reexecute() {
        document.form01.action = '<%=session("pgm_retorno")%>';
        document.form01.submit();
    }

    function CarregaTabela() {
        var str = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: '../../prs/asp/prs0061b_crosbrowser.asp',
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({carregaDados: rsPesquisa}),
            success: function (data) {

                alert(data.carregaDados.nome_tipo_prestador);

                $(data.resultado_acao).each(function () {

                    //str += '<option value=' + this.Acao1 + '>' + this.Acao1 + '</option>';
                })

                //$('#cbxAcao').html(str);

                str = "";

            },
            error: function (error) {
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A principio parece faltar o import do jQuery antes do `jquery-ui.min.js`. Não são a mesma coisa.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, achei que o jquery ui-min fosse suficiente. O que devo incluir? Qual import. Coloque seu comentário como resposta, caso resolva para eu marcar sua resposta.

Comment: @pnet pareçe que falta a referência do Jquery. Inclua-o antes de todos os Scripts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Falta realizar o import do jQuery, exemplo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Ou [baixe o arquivo do site do jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js) e importe:

```
<script src="meusjavascripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Obs.:** As versões 2.x do jQuery não dão suporte as versões inferiores à 9 do Internet Explorer (ou seja: IE8, IE7, IE6 e etc). Caso você não tenha controle dos browsers dos seus usuários utilize a versão 1.x mais recente.

Comment: Valeu, resolveu o problema do $ is not defined.

Comment: Beleza @pnet, boa sorte nessa longa jornada de desenvolvimento web... :v ;)

Comment: no wordpress aonde deve ser adicionado para carregar antes de tudo? No HEADER ??? Teria que fazer uma chamada em functions.php ????

Comment: Oi Paulo, eu nunca trabalhei com Wordpress, mas achei esse link que talvez te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress