# Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript

Preciso de uma aplicação em JS ao qual devo comparar 2 IPs .

Os números iniciais devem ser igual porem o final do 1 IP deve ser sempre maior que o segundo
Exemplo:

```
10.200.1.6 > 10.200.1.2 = true
```

O meu código:

```
var rangeInicio = '10.200.1.6';
var splits = rangeInicio.split('.', 4);
console.log(splits);
var rangeFim = '10.200.1.2';
var splits = rangeFim.split('.', 4);
console.log(splits);


function myFunction() {
    var rangeInicio = "10.200.1.6";
    var rangefim = "10.200.1.2";
    var n = rangeInicio.localeCompare(rangeFim);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}

$(document).ready(function("demo") {

  $("#more").click(function ("demo") {
```

Comment: Seria legal colocar mais informações e código que esta usando

Comment: Você quer que alguém faça essa aplicação pra você?

Comment: @hiago Clique em [edit] e formate sua pergunta. Não dá pra entender absolutamente nada com estes comentários soltos.

Comment: Comentario editado

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88463/problemas-com-uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que esses ips estão no formato string, e que é só o ultimo parametro que muda podes tirar os pontos e tratar como um numero:

```js
function compararIps(a, b) {
  a = Number(a.replace(/\./g, ''));
  b = Number(b.replace(/\./g, ''));
  return a > b;
}

var rangeInicio = '10.200.1.6';
var rangeFim = '10.200.1.2';
console.log(compararIps(rangeInicio, rangeFim));
```

Comment: é isso sergio mt obrigado <3